# Derivative of discrete domain: minimum of a function defined from Combinatorial Analysis

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I am studying the foundations of Combinatory Analysis and found it the following problem:

*A magician appears in public presentation wearing pants and coats of different colors. In order to present his show in 24 sections with distinct coats and pants, what is the minimum number of clothes (pants + coats) he needs?*

I thought something like:
$$
f(x,y) = x + y,
$$
being $f(x,y)$ the number of cloathes, with $x$ the number of pants and $y$ the number of coats. There is a restriction by the Rule of Product, where $x\cdot y = 24$, then $y = 24/x$.

After substitution of the restriction into my $f$ function, we got: $g(x) = x + 24/x$, and I can found the minimum value of $x$ and $y$.

Critical points of function $g$ are $x^*_{1,2} = \pm 2 \sqrt{6}$. Being $g''(x) = 48/x^3 > 0$ only for $x^*_1 = 2\sqrt{6}$, then $g(2\sqrt{6}) = 4\sqrt{6} = 9.79796$ is the minimum number of cloathes.

Of course it is impossible to have 0.79 cloathes, then the most probable answer is 10. Maybe this is because of the definition of my function. I should define $f(x,y)$ as $f:\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$.

**However, how then I evaluate the derivative, in view of the critical point search? Where exactly I am going wrong?**

I know the answer is 10 by doing it by hand, after applying the Multiplication Principle, since it is straightfoward to get two numbers such that $x\cdot y = 24$ and then sum them, but I wonder about the minimum point of a function for obvious reason: 24 is easy, but what if I had like a year of shows of that magician?

Thanks in advance.